# Blazor .net 8 server app using B2C for external authentication with identity authorization issues SSO

Tags: authentication, blazor, authorization, single-sign-on, .net-8.0

I have used the standard .net8 Blazor Web App template to create a Blazor server side web app with Authentication type Individual Accounts (Identity)
Interactive render mode Sever
Include Sample Pages checked

I then created and used a B2C tenant to register the app and added the user flow .etc stuff

Then per some tutorials and docs advice I  added tis to the code:

in appsettings.json

```
    "AzureAdB2C": {
      "Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
      "ClientId": "********",
      "ClientSecret": "****",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
      "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
      "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SiginOnly"
```

in Program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

    // Configure OpenID Connect options
    builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>   //both
            {
                var signInManager =   context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var email = context.Principal.FindFirst("emails")?.Value;
                if (email != null)
                {
                    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // User not found in local Identity system, handle accordingly
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Email claim not found, handle accordingly
                }
            },
        };
    });
```

I also annotated a Blazor page with this to test the challenge:
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

After adding the b2c user and a admin role to the identity tables this actually worked very well - OR SO I THOUHGT.

I worked great with only one app running but when I created a second similar app to test SSO with two registered apps funny things happened like:

1. I would launch App A and then App B
2. Then sign into App A and then App B
3. Then try to logout of App A and I would get this:
   AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
4. Also strange cross app things like logging into one app would would cause the other to appear un-authenticated.

I believe that these issues are cookie related and are probably introduced by this line of code:
await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

But I can't find a way out of this rabbit hole :(

I thought this would be a very desirable thing to do, use external authentication for SSO and use Core Identity to set up roles for authorization (and other stuff)

There are some tutorials and docs that do purport to do this but they all fall short by not actually showing the use of Identity for authenticating on directives like:
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
and not discussing testing using two registered apps to test SSO.

Has anyone got this to work successfully and/or offer advice on how to do this.

Thank you.

Testing using one registered app:
This worked perfectly

Testing using two registered apps:
funny things happened like:

1. I would launch App A and then App B
2. Then sign into App A and then App B
3. Then try to logout of App A and I would get this:
   AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
4. Also strange cross app things like logging into one app would would cause the other to appear un-authenticated.